# Breakpoint stuck at main function

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, program-entry-point

I'm new to iOS App developement and I am sorry in advance if i'm asking anything wrong but my problem is my app stops everytime on main function when i use break point. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? The app is working fine it's just that it stop at main funciton due to break point and i have to press continue every time.

Here is the screenshot :-

[image]

Comment: run your project after removing all breakpoints from the project and check whther it is working fine or not?

Comment: my project is working, it only stop at main function due to break point. @dahiya_boy when i continue the break point it continue as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe You've added an Exception break point..., Add an Objective-C  breakpoint like this :-

[image]